# How do I link a custom dll in Ada?

Tags: dll, ada, gnat

So this is a simple project I put together just to test before doing some cool stuff with it later. The eventual goal is to make the program able to handle modularity through awesome dll kung fu.

But, baby steps. Right now I just want to make the thing link.

Here I have Adder.ads:

```
package Adder is

    function Add(A : Integer; B : Integer) return Integer;

end Adder;
```

And the respective Adder.adb:

```
package body Adder is

    function Add(A : Integer; B : Integer) return Integer is
    begin
        return A + B;
    end Add;

end Adder;
```

Exciting, I know.

I've seen several different tutorials on how to do this, and none of them agree, but taking a cue from [this one](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gnat_ugn/Building-DLLs-with-GNAT.html#Building-DLLs-with-GNAT), I came up with these commands:

```
gnatmake -c Adder.adb
gcc -shared -shared-libgcc -o Adder.dll Adder.o
```

This at least generates *a* dll. I dunno if it generates one that will actually work or if the problem is with the main exe though.

Now the main exe, I have kept everything in a separate directory so gnat doesn't try to cheat and use the .ali and .o files. Then you copy the dll into the directory before trying to build. I've tried this tweaking lots of different ways and gotten several different errors, but here is what I have right now.

Main.adb:

```
with Adder_Spec; use Adder_Spec;
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Main is
begin
    Put_Line(Integer'Image(Add(3,4)));
end Main;
```

Yay most useless program ever. Now, knowing I'm supposed to have a spec for the dll, I came up with the aforewith'd Adder_Spec.ads:

```
package Adder_Spec is

    function Add(A : Integer; B : Integer) return Integer;

private

    pragma Import(Ada, Add, "Add");

end Adder_Spec;
```

Now, like I said I've tried this a bunch of different ways, sometimes omitting the third import parameter, other times omitting the import altogether, sometimes keeping the import but not separating it into the private part, you name it. I've also tried playing with the compile command several ways, but here's the most recent one:

```
gnatmake Main.adb -bargs -shared -largs -lAdder
```

With this particular command it spits out an "Undefined reference to 'Add'" error. If I add the -v flag, it doesn't provide much more useful information.

Checking gnatmake --help shows me that the default mode is gnat 2012, if that makes any difference. It probably shouldn't, as I've tried compiling with the flags for 2005 and 95, too.

So... can anybody savvy enough spot the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Technically this is a GNAT question and not an Ada question (but I think keeping the "ada" tag is most rational anyway).

Comment: When you say `gcc -shared -shared-libgcc -o Adder.dll -Adder.o`, I think you must mean just `Adder.o`?

Comment: @SimonWright yep, good catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to say

```
package Adder_Spec is
    function Add(A : Integer; B : Integer) return Integer;
private
    pragma Import(Ada, Add, "Add");
end Adder_Spec;
```

when importing the DLL, then you have to say

```
package Adder is
    function Add(A : Integer; B : Integer) return Integer;
    pragma Export (Ada, Add, "Add");
end Adder;
```

when building it.

GNAT’s default linker name for the generated `Add` would be (I think) `adder__add`; you should be able to see what it is using `nm Adder.o`.

Comment: AFAIK a pragma export should be declared right after the imported contract definition: no ambiguity left concerning its scope. With the export declared in private part and contract in public part, what would be the expected behaviour anyways ? And why such a construction be needed ?

Comment: @LoneWanderer - If you check [ARM05 B.1(51)](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-B-1.html#p51) you will see the export declared in the private part. I would imagine that there might be a problem if you made use of a subprogram before seeing the pragma, perhaps by declaring a variable initialized to the result of a function call; the idea here and in the example above must be to hide the messy details from the eyes of those who really don’t need to know. Nowadays, of course, the `Convention`, `Export` and `External_Name` aspects are right in your face!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you follow the instructions in "Ada Plug-ins and Shared Libraries" ([part 1](http://www.adacore.com/adaanswers/gems/gem-109-ada-plug-ins-and-shared-libraries-part-1), [part 2](https://www.adacore.com/gems/gem-110-ada-plug-ins-and-shared-libraries-part-2)) from AdaCore.

I've used the technique described there, and it worked quite fine.